# Sync Outlook for Mac contacts with iCloud

Tags: icloud, contacts, exchange-activesync

What is best way to clean up these lists

Outlook for Mac Contacts (via MS 365 Exchange) do not match iCloud contacts.  On iPhone, I can see a large percentage of contacts are linked to both accounts (Exchange and iCloud), but there are many widows and orphans.  All Contacts 5489, Exchange 5439, iCloud 588.

Note: I'm still using Legacy Outlook for Mac bc GUI and search features are inferior in New Outlook

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried to do to ameliorate the problem. There may be many solutions and knowing which ones you tried, but failed, will help other guide you in the right direction. I myself just yesterday bemoaned the sheer number of contacts for people I don't remember, merged from work, two graduate programs class email contacts, etc, but I don't have the massive numbers you have accumulated.

Comment: Response to IconDaemon.  1) I have done a couple hours of google searches that lead me to 3rd party software to manage my contacts (for a price).  2) I spent a couple more hours analyzing the data in the three categories.  Found that 50 contacts were iCloud only contacts.  The other 533 were in both iCloud and Exchange.  Exported the 50 to another data file and imported into exchange.  Then I executed a back up of everything followed by deleting the contacts in iCloud.  I will run that way until I can find a way to sync contacts again.